# How do I get a return of multiple strings from a list?

Tags: list

I want this `("start" "--color=always" "--exclude=*pdf" "end")` but I am getting this `("start" ("--color=always" "--exclude=*pdf") "end")`.

Here are the things that I have tried. I have also tried split-string but that also returns a list. I need something that returns strings so that I can send them as arguments to list.

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results output
(print (list "start"   (dolist (x '("--color=always" "--exclude=*pdf" "--exclude=*tex"))  (concat x) "end"))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 
: ("start" nil "end")

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results output
(print (list "start" (mapcar (lambda(x)(concat x))(split-string "--color=always --exclude=*pdf")) "end"))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 
: ("start" ("--color=always" "--exclude=*pdf") "end")
```

Not sure why I get two ':' in the results.

---

Update by OP:

Although both answers work, flatten-tree is what I needed and the easiest way. The other answer works as well but had to do some modifications (see commented code).

```
(append
 (flatten-tree
  (list consult--fd-command ;; `(,consult--fd-command)
        my/fd-flags ;; my/fd-flags ; '("--color=never" "--extension=org")
       (consult--join-regexps re 'extended))) ;; `(,(consult--join-regexps re 'extended))
opts)
```

Comment: @dalanicolai Hello, there's a lot of complex code that creates "start" and "end". It would be a long post if I included all the code but basically trying to set the flags in this: `(when re
      (cons (append
             (list consult--fd-command
                   "--color=never"
                   (consult--join-regexps re 'extended))
             opts)
            hl))))`

Comment: That does not make your goal much clearer:) Anyway, I already deleted my comment, because I figured you wanted to 'splice' the 'inner' list. If that is not what you mean, then please try to explain again what you try to achieve (please by editing your question, and not via a comment. Thanks!)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

> `(flatten-tree TREE)`
>
> Return a "flattened" copy of TREE.

```lisp
(flatten-tree '(1 (2 3) 4))
;; ⇒ (1 2 3 4)
```

```lisp
(flatten-tree '(1 
                  (2 
                     (3
                        (4)
                      5)
                   6)
                7))
;; ⇒ (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT

To complete the answer:
The two `:`'s are printed because `print` always adds a newline before the output (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Functions.html). You could replace `print` with `prin1` or you could use `:results raw` instead.

So the following code would achieve what you ask for:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results output
(prin1 `("start" ,@(mapcar (lambda(x)(concat x))(split-string "--color=always --exclude=*pdf")) "end"))
#+end_src
```

To evaluate the 'complex code' that produce "start" and "end" (as you mention in the comment), you can add additional `,`'s in front of those expressions (again see [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html)).

END EDIT

Do you mean that you want to 'splice' the list withing the 'surrounding' list?

You can achieve it either via `append`:

```lisp
(append '("start") '("--color=always" "--exclude=*pdf" "--exclude=*tex") '("end"))
```

or you can use [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) syntax:

```lisp
`("start" ,@'("--color=always" "--exclude=*pdf" "--exclude=*tex") "end")
```

Comment: Your ideas gave me the answer I needed that is correct. Working on posting the final solution. I think I will edit the answer to post the solution or comment. It's been a while since I've asked a question lol. The solution was to use append with multiple arguments.