# How to unpack lists regardless of the depth?

Tags: list

I want to have a function that does the following

Input

```
'(1 (2) (3))
'(1 (2) ((3 4)))
'(1 (2) ((3 4) (5 6)))
'(1 (2) ((3 4) (5 6 (7 8))))
'(1 (2) ((3 4) (5 6 (7 8 (9 10)))))
```

Output

```
'(1 2 3)
'(1 2 3 4)
'(1 2 3 4 5 6)
'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a return of multiple strings from a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/75870/how-do-i-get-a-return-of-multiple-strings-from-a-list) |||| Please ignore that question's description and just see its answer. The OP of that question didn't do a good job of extracting the essence of the problem and thus gave that question a bad title -- it is inconvenient for others who come up with the same question to search for it. Your question's title is better.

Comment: ... ot use `-flatten` from the `dash.el` package: it's available from MELPA.

Comment: Code a classic `flatten` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this recursively:

```lisp
(defun unpack-list (lst)
  (cond
    ((null lst) '()) ; Base case: if the list is empty, return an empty list
    ((atom lst) (list lst)) ; Base case: if the element is not a list, return a list with that element
    (t (apply 'append (mapcar #'unpack-list lst))))) ; Recursively unpack nested lists
```